# PHP Edit user information form database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create an admin panel, that can manage users. I load all my users into an HTML table, to display the users. This is the code i use:

```php
<table class="users">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>HWID</th>
        <th>User action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <?php
            if($resultCheck > 0){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hwid'] . "</td><td><a href='#'><i class='fas fa-sync'></i></a> <a href='#'><i class='fas fa-gavel'></i></a></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

And it looks something like this
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg8Mg.png)

How do i go about making the buttons work for the listed user?

Comment: _How do i go about making the buttons work for the listed user..._ How it is supposed to work? What it is supposed to do? Also what is not working at the moment? What errors?

Comment: @B001ᛦ When you click, for example, the gavle, it's supposed to ban the user.

Comment: _..the gavle, it's supposed to ban the user..._ So where is your code?

Comment: @B001ᛦ What i'm trying to figure out, is how to make it so that when i click the button, it knows which user i'm trying to ban.(the user on the same line)

Comment: Each user will have a user id coming from db. Use the user id for that

Comment: You want to add a unique identifier with each button that somehow resonates to which user it belongs to, so that when you click on the button you know which user to ban, and then you can use your function to ban the user.

Comment: @B001ᛦ What code are you talking about?

Comment: _What code are you talking about?_ The code that is trying to ban the user

Comment: Thanks both of you! Can't believe i didn't think of that...

Comment: @B001ᛦ i don't have a problem with the banning of the user, it's making php know that when i click the button, it knows which user to edit.